# GWT - Charts - Large Dataset getting unresponsive warnings

Tags: gwt, dataset, google-visualization

I'm working on learning GWT and made a little side project app that runs roulette system simulations.  I'm rendering the results using the visualization API for GWT in a line chart.

I've found if results go above charting 1K data points I start getting unresponsive script warnings from Firefox and Chrome and IE basically explodes no matter what.

Is the hang up in rendering the graph from the google server side or on the client machine?  Not sure I'm understanding the mechanics involved.

In terms of solutions:

1) If it's a client side problem could I somehow send the data to my server side, instantiate the chart there, and simply return it completed to the browser asynchronously instead of hogging client resources?

2) Or is the visualization API simply not able to deal with so many data points?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The GWT-Visualization connect to google servers to download library, but the renders are done at client side. Your are not able to render on server side using it.
 I can also confirm that Visuazation in not able to deal with ~1K point.
You can give a try to other server side GWT libraries like GFlot or clientsidegchart.
For server side render you can user any graph library for java (eg.JGraph). Just create a graph image and download it to your side. This way you receive static image but without hangings on client side.

Comment: I have about 10k points loaded to annotated timeline and it works fine

Comment: So maybe a browser is a issue ? I did a check on Chrome 16.0.912.77 m

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are loading values one by one with addValue().
There's a method addRows which receives an array of values that is not implemented in the GWT Visualization library. This could be a faster way of loading your data.
Check [GWT Charts](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-charts/)